# Transform JSON Columns into single column JSON request .net

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json

When requesting a JSON GET I receive the following:

```
[
  [ "1731950",
   "1764966",
   "1771940",
   "1931966" ]
```

I would like this to be transformed to one column with the following values instead of four separate columns from the array. c#, .net would be the best choice of programming language.

```
id
1731950
1764966
1771940
1931966
```

Comment: can you describe what do you mean by `one column` here? can you show us expected output? is it single element containing all values like `["1731950, 1764966, 1771940, 1931966"]`

Comment: Please, show us what have you tried

Comment: Your JSON is not well-formed, it is missing a closing `]`.  Can you please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] including well-formed JSON and some definition of your desired "one column" data model (as c# classes)?

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are exactly trying to achieve (as per comments). You can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) framework, install it into your .NET project through the Nuget Package Manager or through the Package Manager Console typing:

`PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Then you can deserialize a collection to the list of strings:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private static List<string> GetListOfIds(string jsonResponse)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonResponse);
}
```

I assume that your JSON is array of strings.

If you need exactly the string how did you describe, you can make this conversion:

```
var records = GetListOfIds(jsonResponse);
records.Insert(0, "id");
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, records.ToArray());
```